# Getting "Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name" in Rmd file in RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

In RStudio, I am getting 'Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name' in the following R code block:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
pb52_in <- read.csv("../data/pb52.csv", T)
pb52 <- pb52_in
```
````

This is the output:

```
Show in New Window
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> # knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
> pb52_in <- read.csv("../data/pb52.csv", T)
> pb52 <- pb52_in
> 
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

I haven't modified the file yet, and I am only running this code block. This is my first time using Rstudio and working with R, so I am a little lost. I checked for other similar questions, and they said to check for the correct formatting of ```; I tried that but without success.

Comment: So you've saved the file with an Rmd extension? Did you also include the YAML header information in the Rmd file? What does the full source of your file up to this code look like? It sounds like the problem is that RStudio doesn't current know that you are trying to run an Rmarkdown file and is assuming everything is R code (which it's not).

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I think you were on the right path. I posted the solution below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Hopefully, it will help others:

After the code block:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
pb52_in <- read.csv("../data/pb52.csv", T)
pb52 <- pb52_in
```
````

I have this:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "XX/XX/XXXX"
output: html_document
---
```

I added an empty line between the last "```" and "---", and that solved the issue